# From which scripture the following "108 names of Subrahmanya" is taken?

Tags: scripture, kartikeya, ashtottara-shatanamavali

Subrahmanya ashtothara sathanaamavali is popular among the ashtothara namas of several deities. I am asking this question about the 108 names of the Subrahmanya swami that start with **Skandaya**. You can check the names [here](https://www.drikpanchang.com/hindu-names/gods/lord-murugan/108-murugan-names.html).

Although there are several sites [1](https://www.docdroid.net/heh16x4/subrahmanya-ashttotaram-pdf), [2](https://templesinindiainfo.com/108-names-of-sri-subrahmanya-siddhanama-1-lyrics-in-english/), [3](http://joyfulslokas.blogspot.com/2010/08/subramanya-ashtotaram.html), [4](https://indianhindunames.com/108-names-murugan-ashtottara-shatanaamavali.htm), [5](https://nriol.com/indianparents/lord-muruga.asp), [6](https://www.hindudevotionalblog.com/2014/01/subrahmanya-ashtothram-108-names-muruga.html), [7](https://www.templepurohit.com/mantras-slokas-stotras/murugan-mantra/) and videos containing all the names, none mentions the source scripture.

I want to know the rishi, audience, and phalashruti of the  Subrahmanya ashtothara sathanaamavali mentioned above.

What is the name of the scripture that contains it?

**Note**: I found *another* 108 names of Karthikeya in the [KamaKoti](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana10.html) site that contains all the details. The question is not about this one.